# Certain Phones delete SQLite DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've got an app created with Android Studio.

I'm using an SQLite database which gets downloaded and saved in phone's storage.
The problem is that in certain types of phones (Lenovo / Xiaomi to be exact) the sqlite file gets deleted after some time and the users have to re-download it.

The problem is appearing only on these 2 types of phones and also not all of them.
I can't replicate that on any of the phones I tried nor emulated ones within Android Studio.
There is no code that would delete the SQLite file and also I couldn't find anything in here or google about Lenovo/Xiaomi having similar problems like mine.

Any Ideas, would be appreciated.

Comment: at any time a user could just delete their cache and this would happen, if it's not a DB they built up themselves, just tell the user they need to sync again (if you aren't already, using a sync adapter would be good too), if you need to persist a unique table for each user, you could consider using something like Firebase or some other cloud db solution

Comment: I tried deleting app's cache on a couple phones but none of them removed the sqlite db.
The file is getting saved on phone's storage(not sd)/Android/data/app folder/db.sqlite.
Also the table has some unique data for every user saved in it.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to say "cache/data"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Lenovo, but Xiaomi phones have a "Clean up" feature that regularly (at least once a week, in my experience) asks the user to, well, let it clean up files. I don't know what it uses to decide if a file is obsolete or not, but it is a very aggressive cleaner (it wants to clean up cache files for apps that have just been used and are in constant use, for example). This is likely what is removing your downloaded files. You can check the location you're downloading them to, and see if changing that helps; or you could see if you can find any documentation on the file cleaner so you can find out how to stop it from flagging your DB as "rubbish".

Comment: Thanks,I'll look into Xiaomi's cleaner.

Comment: It seem's that the native cleaner Xiaomi phones use have a "deep clean" feature, that can erase the data of an app that haven't been used for while. That might be the reason behind it.Thanks for the info.